# Как в DLE определить путь к файлу?

Tags: data-life-engine

У меня есть сайт сделанный на DLE, хотел добавить свой код, но не могу найти путь к файлу, например в коде:

```
<div class="player">
              <img class="player2" src=[xfvalue_videopathimage] width="506" height="506" >
              <video class="player__video" width="506" height="506" muted preload="auto">
                  <source src="[xfvalue_videopath]" type="video/mp4">
                  Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
```

путь написан как  `src=[xfvalue_videopathimage]` и `src="[xfvalue_videopath]"`, как я могу найти путь к видео и картинкам, и как оно обрабатывает эти картинки?

в файле `xfield.txt` есть:

```
videopath|путь для видео |97|text||1|0|0|0
videopathimage|превью видео|97|text||1|0|0|0
```

вот такие строчки, и как понимаю без них оно не показывает видео и картинки на сайте, объясните как это работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заходите на хостинг, файловый менеджер, в поисковой строке(если она есть, если нет, то через меню менеджера) вводите название файла или название расширения файла (***.mp4 или другое расширение, которое вы используете), поиск найдет файл и покажет путь.